# Is there a rails gem that pulls tweets from twitter into a object I can iterate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Is there a ruby gem that will pull all recent tweets and pack it into a nice ruby object I can just iterate from and display on a web page?

Answer (score 5):

Here you go - http://twitter.rubyforge.org/

I use this with my plugin on Heroku as well. It is working fine.

```
oauth = Twitter::OAuth.new('consumer token', 'consumer secret')
oauth.authorize_from_access('access token', 'access secret')

client = Twitter::Base.new(oauth)
client.friends_timeline.each  { |tweet| puts tweet.inspect }
```

then you can just display a timeline as you want.

Comment: I just want my own tweets, so I don't really even need any tokens etc.